# Nested Dictionray<T,V> to Nested ConcurrentDictionary<T,V>

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I am looking for the best practice to go from a:

```
Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dicionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>>>
```

To:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string,ConcurrentDictionary<string,ConcurrentDictionary<string,string>>>>
```

When the level of nesting can vary. I was trying to use generics but can't get past the first level of nesting.

Comment: If you need that kind of dictionary nesting, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: I'd agree, but at this point I'm trying to find the most elegant want to convert it to what is required...

Answer (score 2):

You seem to need a tree data structure. Wrap the dictionaries in a class:

```
class MyNode {
 Dictionary<string, MyNode> children = ...;
}
```

Now you can go arbitrarily deep. The recursive generics are avoided.

Answer (score 1):

You may need a custom data structure to hold this hierarchy. Have you thought about using a tree?

You could try combining several levels of keys using tuples. For example

```
ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<string,string>, ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>>
```

or

```
ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<string,string,string>, string>
```